# jQuery: click() executes instead of binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to bind a click event to a function; this happens into a REST get request :

```js
$.get(Constants.webServices.rest.get.pointings(),params,function(data){
    var json = eval(data);
    for(var i=0; i<json.length;i++){
        [...]
        $('a').click(__applyPointing(json[i],originalParams))
        [...]
    }
}
```

But instead of simply binding, this code executes the function, which is for the moment:

```js
__applyPointing: function(item,originalParams){
    console.log('applyPointing');
    console.log(item);
}
```

I also tried with bind('click') and on('click'), same result. My js debugger seems useless with an asynchronous request. Please advise.

Comment: You're calling the function, and passing its return value to bind against. You need to pass a reference to a function, meaning no `()` after you name it! F. Calderan's answer is good if you know what the parameters to your function are, as you do in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change

```
$(a).click(__applyPointing(json[i],originalParams))
```

in

```
(function(i) {
    $(a).click(function() { __applyPointing(json[i],originalParams) })
}(i))
```

it's useful wrap the binding into a closure so `json[i]` is properly passed

Edit: please note that you wrote `$(a)` and maybe you may want to write `$('a')`

Comment: Yes it could be, but it could also be a variable containing a DOM reference

Comment: Indeed, though I don't see any.  I thought it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. The $.get turns out to have nothing to do with my problem, I will edit my title.
And indeed, my `a` is a variable containing a <a>. It's part of the [...], sorry about that, I will add it.